# How can I align two integer arrays by index in C?

Tags: c, arrays, math

I know the question may not seem very clear.

Basically I'm trying to code a program that displays elementary arithmetic calculations (via the console of course) in the same way kids would do.

For instance:

5,294 
+ 0,706

= etc

So I have both numbers in separate arrays, split up by digit (so an int array like: {5,2,9,4}).

What I'm trying to learn/figure out is how I would align both sets of digits to the right if they didn't have the same number of digits. For example if instead of 0,706 I had just 706? Currently I would have two arrays, one like {5,2,9,4} and another like so: {7,0,6} – I would need the 4 to be over the 6.

Hopefully that makes sense to you all!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try?  hint: use the maximum length, go from left to right, if your index>=len output '0'.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Have you any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: Why don't you store them from left to right and print them in the opposite side. It would be easier to calculate and always aligned.
ex. 124 will be {4,2,1}

Comment: I tried a couple different ways to do it using length of each array and then placing zeros on one side of the smaller number in order to align them. Wasn't sure if there was a better way to do it or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code snippet might generate the sort of output you're looking for, it works with ordinary integers so you don't need to mess around with arrays:

```
char tmpstr[1];
int total = first + second;
int width = snprintf(tmpstr, 1, "%d", total);
printf("  %*d\n", width, first);
printf("+ %*d\n", width, second);
printf("  %.*s\n", width, "-----------");
printf("= %*d\n", width, total);
```

Comment: Yeah that would be the more obvious way to do it. Unfortunately I plan to do subtraction/multiplication/division with very large numbers, so I need my code to be capable of high precision, hence why I'm using arrays instead that encapsulate each digit individually.

Comment: @Josh How hard would it be to use strings instead? You could easily right-justify them using the `%*s` format.

Comment: originally I was thinking of using a char array but I would still need to convert everything to int though for each operation. Unless you're thinking differently?

Comment: @Josh I guess you could do your calculations using integers stored in a char array and then convert them to ASCII before printing them but you would have to remember to allow for the trailing `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply look for the length of every single array and find the longest length. Then creating new arrays for every array that does not have that length and start filling these arrays first with the numbers of the old short array and then for the rest of the values fill them up with zeros until you reach index 0. I hope I did understand your question correctly to answer your question with my proposal.

That is of course only valid, if there is no decimal point involved. If there is a decimal point involved you would have to find the maximum number of digits to the left and to the right of that and then create new arrays for every old array that do not meet this criteria and do the same thing as above.

**Edit:** An even easier way to do it, could be simply by reversing the order of every array, then do your calculations, but carrying the numbers to the right (and not left) and in the end reverse the order of the result.

Comment: If we disregard the possibility of there being a decimal point for now (think very basic arithmetic), how would I go about shifting numbers down to provide room for the zeros? Just iterate backwards through the array and have each index re-initialized to i+1?

Comment: Say you have an array with length 5 and with length 3. You check for lengths and find the longest to be 5. You see there is one array with length not 5 (3) and create a new array with length 5. Then you start filling the new array backwards with the values of the array of length 3 (also from the back) and fill the rest of the spaces in the front with zeros.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that makes sense. I originally had the idea but wasn't sure how best to implement it. If I try going about the method you just edited in, then wouldn't the rest of the indexes be random information instead of 0? I mean the trailing digits after reversing. Say one length is 5 and the other is 3, even if I reverse the order, I still need to initialize those zeros to balance it out, right?

Comment: Well then you can simply loop from 0 to "largest index" and add every array up in that loop but check for every array, if the current loop number is higher than its maximum index to avoid OutOfRange problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need information about your decimal point within your array. Else you could just use integers. I would take the exponent to the base of 10 and make it either my first or my last entry. Once you have this you can use it for shifting your formatting accordingly.

´0,706´ would become ´{-3, 7, 0, 6}´ the first number being the exponent. Then you align your comma like this

```
//0 -1 -2 -3
   ,  
   ,
```

and then just put in your number

```
//0 -1 -2 -3
  0, 7  0  6
   ,
```

Rinse and repeat.